# Regex match everything between &foo= until it appears again

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using JavaScript and I need a regex expression to match everything between "foo".

When I use the following string.

```
&foo=test1&foo=test2&foo=test3%20test4
```

It should return

```
match1: test1
match2: test2
match3: test3%20test4
```

I tried the following expression

```
((&foo=)(.*))*
```

but unfortunately it returned the whole string.

How can I improve my regex expression?

Comment: If there is no qs other than `foo` then `foo=([^&]+)` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression does not uses `.*`, instead it might be safe to add a list of chars in between `foo=` and the next `&`, maybe similar to:

```
foo=([A-z0-9%]+)&?
```

Then, using capturing groups you can capture anything that you might want to.

You can test/modify/change/practice your expressions in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YdMudz/1), if you like.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualizes your expressions:

[image]

- You can add additional boundaries to your expressions, if it might be necessary.
- You can also expand your list of chars.

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /foo=([A-z0-9%]+)&?/gm;
const str = `&foo=test1&foo=test2&foo=test3%20test4&foo=test1&foo=test2&foo=test3%20test4&foo=test1&foo=test2&foo=test3%20test4`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Edit

Based on [toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto)'s advice, it's much better to change `A-z` to `A-Za-z` or you can use `a-z` with flag `i`, based on Limbo's advice, since `A-z` also passes some other chars such as `[` and `]`.

```
foo=([A-Z-a-z0-9%]+)&?
```

Comment: `[A-z]` matches more tan letters, see an ASCII table.

Comment: ...or use flag `i`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using regular expressions at all, I suggest using the built-in `URLSearchParams` class:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams('&foo=test1&foo=test2&foo=test3%20test4');

params.getAll('foo');
// ["test1", "test2", "test3 test4"]
```

Works in all major browsers. (Needs a polyfill for IE 11, if that matters to you.)

Answer (score 1):

This works, save capture group 1 to an array.

`&foo=([\S\s]*?)(?=&foo=|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/I5JiIc/1